# slicing a list of urls based on a condition

Tags: python

I have a list of urls like this :

```
 'https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine/mentions-legales.shtml',
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser/article',
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/planete/index.html',
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/live',
```

And I want to write a function that can return a url sliced based on a condition : if the end of the url is ending with article or html or php

so the desired result would be like this :

```
 'https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine/,
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser/,
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/planete/,
 'https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/live',
```

Comment: You need to indent then final line (within the `if` statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> a = "https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine/mentions-legales.shtml"
>>> a.rsplit('/', 1)
['https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine', 'mentions-legales.shtml']
```

On brief:

```
>>> url_list = ['https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine/mentions-legales.shtml',
...  'https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser/article',
...  'https://www.lemonde.fr/planete/index.html',
...  'https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/live']
>>> parse_list = []
>>> for single_url in url_list:
...   parse_list.append(single_url.rsplit('/', 1)[0])
...
>>> print(parse_list)
['https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine', 'https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser', 'https://www.lemonde.fr/planete', 'https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs']
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
ls = [
    "https://www.journaldunet.com/magazine/mentions-legales.shtml",
    "https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser/article",
    "https://www.lemonde.fr/planete/index.html",
    "https://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/live",
]
newls = []
for url in ls:
    if url.endswith("html") or url.endswith("php") or url.endswith("article"):
        newls.append(url.rsplit("/", 1)[0])
    else:
        newls.append(url)
print(newls)
```

Comment: @fati shouldn't this be the accepted answer? The other one doesn't work properly with the last url

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex which would be easier to update if needed:

```
re.sub(r'/[^/]*?(article|html|php)$', '/', some_url)
```

You can make it a bit more restrictive by adding `\.php` or `\.\w?html`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the extension :

```
last_index = url.rfind(".")
sep = [url[:last_index], [url[last_index:]]]
```

Then, you keep only the url if it has the right extension (with a `filter` maybe)